# I want design a metro style UI for my android app

Tags: microsoft-metro, android

I want to design metro style UI for my android app. How to do it? is there any shortcuts? I tried to make one using Image views. How to give effects for it? Is there any other way to do it? Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Metro UI CSS by Sergey Pimenov. Check http://metroui.org.ua/

Comment: How is this for an android app?